# how to get the Facebook activity feed bigger than 500px (width) on my website

Tags: css, html, facebook

How can I get the Facebook activity feed bigger than 500 pixels (width) on my website?
 [image]

Comment: cool, where is the code ?

Comment: How much bigger do you want it anyway

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) are pretty clear on this one

> The plugin will by default adapt to the width of its parent container on page load (min. 180px / **max. 500px**), useful for changing layout:

And it appears hard-coded on the plugin to never go above 500px. I'm sure there's some way you can work it into your design though :)